# RxJS - Subscription in Subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscription

I wanted to know, if there is a better solution then i have.
I have a subscription to get an ID. With that ID i have to get another subscription.

It looks like this:

```js
this.store
      .select<string>(ClubStateSelectors.CurrentUid)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribe$))
      .subscribe(clubUid => {
        if (clubUid) {
          this.clubUid = clubUid;
          this._ngUnsubscribePayoutstructures$.next();
          this.payoutstructureSubscription();
          this._ngUnsubscribeTournament$.next();
          this.tournamentSubscription();
          this._ngUnsubscribeRanking$.next();
          this.rankingSubscription();
          this._ngUnsubscribeMembership$.next();
          this.membershipSubscription();
        }
      });
```

And this for example is then the subscription i will run

```
public membershipSubscription(): void {
    if (this.clubUid) {
      this.tournamentService
        .getCollectionData(this.tournamentService.membershipCollection(this.clubUid))
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribeMembership$))
        .subscribe((membershipDocs: firestoremodels.Membership[]) => {
          this.memberships = membershipDocs;
        });
    }
  }
```

I thought about switchmap, but then i have to do the select of `clubUid^multiple times.

Comment: So the end goal is to get in some variables the `payoutStructure` `tournaments` and `memberships` with single subscribe?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about switchmap, but then i have to do the select of `clubUid^multiple times.

That is fine, just add `shareReplay`

```
const clubId$ = this.store.select<string>(ClubStateSelectors.CurrentUid).pipe(
  shareReplay({ buffersize: 1, refCount: true });
);

clubId$.pipe(
  filter(clubId => !!clubId),
  switchMap(clubId =>  this.tournamentService.getCollectionData(this.tournamentService.membershipCollection(clubUid))),
  takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribeMembership$),
).subscribe((membershipDocs: firestoremodels.Membership[]) => {
  this.memberships = membershipDocs;
});

// your other subscriptions
```